# No working init found

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04, kernel

I tried to update my kernel in Ubuntu and booting into it does not work. I can still boot with my old kernel by going into advanced boot options and selecting the previous kernel but I would like to get 4.7 working.

The error message is something about a working init not being found and it is asking for an init= to be set in the boot options.

I have no idea what is going on here. Can someone help?

[image: Image of error message here]

Comment: We need the exact error message.  We can assist you by using the output to search how others with a similar issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clue is in line "Starting init: /bin/sh exists but couldn't execute it (error -8)"

A check in [errno.h](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno) says the 8 is "Exec format error".

Are you trying to run a 32 bit kernel on a filesystem with 64 bit userspace?

Comment: I am much dumber than you estimate. How do I find out if this is my mistake?

Comment: @MindlessMutagen Tell us which kernel you downloaded, the one ending in amd64.deb (64 bit) or the one ending in i386 .deb(the 32 bit).

Comment: Additionally please update your question with the output of `uname -a`

Comment: I am a moron who downloaded the i386 kernel. You have been greatly helpful but I still feel like a moron. Thanks

Comment: We all make computer mistakes, indeed those who use it the most probably make the most.

Comment: No need to use dumb, moron, etc. You made a mistake, we were happy to help you fix it and now you will not make the same mistake again. Hopefully somebody else will learn from that episode. Lets leave it at that, without the self-insults, OK?